# How to debug Azure Emulator in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2013

I follow instruction on https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ff683670.aspx to debug a project in Azure Emulator in Visual Studio 2013. But after clicking "Show Compute Emulator UI", I can not find "Debug" On the Azure compute emulator (express) menu bar. What is the problem? Thanks for help.

Comment: You need to run the debug command from Visual Studio, not the compute emulator.  Set the Azure project in Visual Studio as the Start Up Project, and you'll be able to hit `F5` and have debugging start.

Comment: After running debug command (F5) from Visual Studio 2013, application is launched but won't stop at break point.

Comment: Which break point?  It's time to show some code so that we can see what's going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make sure that you have the correct project set as the Startup Project.

For example:
[image]

The `Azure` project here includes a `Worker Role` that is implemented in the `Azure.Processor` project.

With the `Azure` project as the startup project, hitting `F5` will build the package, deploy it to the emulator, start it up and attach the debugger.

Comment: How to attach the debugger in VS2013?

Comment: You don't need to do it manually.  1. Set the Azure Project as the Startup Project; 2. press `F5` to start with debugging; 3. Do some debugging.  Do you have breakpoints set in your code?  Do you see the emulator launch?  It's time to start providing some more detail for anyone to help further.

Comment: After removing Azure project as Startup Project, I can set breakpoints and debug the program. I do not really need to debug in Azure simulator. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Brendan Green: When creating a azure project, is it always needed to create a worker role? What is use of worker role?

Comment: Because you can add one or more web and/or worker roles to an Azure Cloud Service project.  A worker role is nothing more than a class library that implements `RoleEntryPoint`, which Azure knows how to run.

Comment: Yes.  Otherwise it has nothing to execute.  I am starting to think that you had no roles in your Azure project.

Comment: There is no worker role in my Azure project. I link webrole to an existing old MVC project (MVC 2), which could cause the trouble of not debugging correctly.

Comment: Web role or worker role.  At this point, we have no idea what the structure of your project is.  Reading between the lines you have a web role that you've added to an azure cloud service project, but you're not hitting any breakpoints when running via the Compute Emulator, but are when running the MVC project on its own (say, via IIS Express)?  I asked earlier but had no response - where is the breakpoint?

Comment: Breakpoint is in the web project. When creating web project through web role (MVC 5 is created), breakpoint is enabled. When linking an old MVC project (MVC 2) through web role, breakpoint is disabled. But I can not change old MVC project (MVC 2) to MVC 5 because too much modification will incur.

Comment: WHERE in the code?  I have found that sometimes having a breakpoint inside `global.asax.cs` won't get hit if, for example, running under full IIS.  If this is the case, have you tried a breakpoint in a controller instead?

Comment: In the web project through web role (MVC 5 is created), breakpoint is enabled even without workrole (breakpoint is in global.asax.cs).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to click "Debug" in emulator UI. I think the document may be wrong. Just clicked "F5" to launch your application from VS2013 if it's built in debug. Once the emulator was started and your application was running, you can begin to debug by adding breakpoint.

Comment: No, it does not work that way. After F5, it launches application from VS 2013 but never stops at breakpoint.

Comment: Which project have you got set as the Start Up Project?  It needs to be the Azure project, and *not* the role class library project.